# How to create a neon light effect in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics

I tried to use `Glow` to create a neon light effect on a [torus object](https://www.dropbox.com/s/107ofrrrk2qxmlu/torus.obj?dl=0). The result shown on the left of the picture below looks quite different from the real one on the right. Is there a way to obtain a better result?

```
(* Assuming the .obj file located in the root of c: *)
model =  Import["c:\\torus.obj"] ;
 Graphics3D[{Glow[Cyan], First[model ] }, Boxed -> False ,
 Background -> Black
  ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This rasters the image first and then applies a convolution to the 2d image. At the end, the result is combined whith the image rendered with "Glow":

```
model = Import["../torus.obj"];
hColor = RGBColor[0.2, 0.5, 1];
img = Graphics3D[{hColor, Opacity[0.5], EdgeForm[hColor], 
   First[model][[2 ;; -1]]}, Boxed -> False, Background -> Black];
img0 = Graphics3D[{Glow[Cyan], Opacity[0.9], First[model]}, 
   Boxed -> False, Background -> Black];
cv = Table[
ImageMultiply[ImageConvolve[img, GaussianMatrix[{r, r/3}]], 
r/15], {r, {10, 50, 150}}];
ImageAdd[img0, ImageAdd[cv]]
```

[image]

You might have to play a bit with the parameters to get the desired result.